# Transition with hidden elements

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a text which on hover displays another (otherwise hidden) text elsewhere, like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="design">hover me<span>to show this</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.design {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #404040;
}

.design:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.design span {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.design:hover span {
    display: block;
    top: 47px;
    left: 45px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
}
```

How can apply transition effects to the text which is hidden or shown depending on the hover? Apparently `transition` conflicts with `display:none` and `:block`, but using `visibility` doesn't seem to work either.

edit: jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vwsgJ/

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200141/animating-an-element-when-hovering-on-two-other-element-using-css.. Hope this will help you...

Comment: And you can create a jsfiddle for your question http://jsfiddle.net/. This will help others to give you a better answer:)

Comment: Added the jsFiddle, thanks. However I can't figure out help from the other topic you linked.

Comment: hope this will help too.i created this using rgba -->http://jsfiddle.net/vwsgJ/1/

Comment: Thanks, but same issue as below; hovering the hidden text causes it to show.

Comment: Use `opacity = 0` and `1`, `transition` only works on numeric values!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First method

I have managed to achieve what you wanted using `opacity`, according to (I think) MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) you can't transition display. I also rearranged your css slightly:

http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/xFDIl - Working Code.

CSS:

```
.design span {
position: absolute;
opacity:0;
transition: opacity 1s;

display: block;
top: 47px;
left: 45px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 13px;
color: #000;

width:0;
height:0;
margin-left:-1000px;
```

}

```
.design:hover span {

opacity:1;
/*transition: all 1s;*/

width:30px;
height:auto;
margin-left:0;
}
```

Note that codepen.io uses prefix-free, see http://caniuse.com/css-transitions for browser support, prefixes may have to be added.

**Edit-** to avoid the OP's problem below, add: `width:0; height:0;` to the un-hovered element, and a pixel width/height such as `width:30px; height:auto;` on hover. (See example) There is if you hover over *precisely* that area you see the hover effect, but in practice this would be very rare in my view, also this can be solved by the use of `margin left` if needed.

Note: this stops the transition on mouse out.

### New Method

To avoid the problem mentioned above, the property `pointer-events:none` can be added to the `span`. This removes the need to have any negative `margins`, or custom `widths` or `heights`.

See http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/BojpK

However, this is not supported in IE-anything, see [css 'pointer-events' property alternative for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie) for maybe more help.

Otherwise I don't think the OP's aim can be **completely** met.

Comment: Thanks, that _almost_ solves the problem, but as you can see, hovering the hidden "to show this" text (if/when you know its position) also causes it to show. That's also why I went with `display` in the first place. Any way around this?

Comment: @lapingultah Fixed using `width`- see answer

Comment: @lapingultah Also, `height`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, repeatable with CodePen and jsFiddle. Shouldn't be a browser issue (FF 21.0).

Comment: Actually acting even more strange that way, http://jsfiddle.net/STYJg/. Sufficient to hover anywhere within the text area.

Comment: @lapingultah That's because you declared `width` twice.

Comment: That circumvents the issue, but kills fade-out transition as well.