# Dropdown Hover CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Can someonehelp me to fix that dropdown menu that this site has [neowin.net](http://www.neowin.net)?

So far I have this; [itbataljonen.com/test/](http://itbataljonen.com/test/) (Hover over "News")

What I can't figure out, is when i hover over for instance `"News" -> "Apple"`, there should come some news with pictures, and they change if I hover over `"Microsoft"` and so on.

Could this be done via CSS or HTML?

To download the source files, just go to [www.ITbataljonen.com/test](http://www.ITbataljonen.com/test) and click Download Source in the navigation bar.

Can someone help me? :) (Sorry for my bad english..)

Comment: Please add corresponding code snippets to your post.

Comment: Yes. just use `display:block` and `display:none` with animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kw2stspx/4/)

As you asked using css. Yes by using css it is possible to hide and show another div. You need to simply write hover event. This applies to "apple" and "microsoft" also.

Here is the **css:**

```
#a:hover + #b {
 background: #ccc;
    visibility: visible;
}
#b{
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using hover property in CSS.
Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200141/animating-an-element-when-hovering-on-two-other-element-using-css) to understand more.

And in your case, the images can be in a `<ul id="news_images1"></ul>` and you can set css hover property to animate this list of images. Remember, there are multiple ways to solve this issue. You can also checkout Jquery hover.